# JQUERY evaluate a string

Tags: jquery, eval

I wanted to evaluate this script in jquery:

```
var name = "Brian";
var txt = "This is your {name}";
```

Anyone can help me? I'm very noob for this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could concatenate:

```
var name = "Brian"; 
var txt = "This is your " + name;
```

or you could replace your *placeholder*:

```
var name = "Brian"; 
var txt = "This is your {name}";

txt = txt.replace('{name}', name);
```

If you want more sophisticated string formatting I recommend you to give a look to the [StringFormat](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/StringFormat) jQuery plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = "Brian";  
var txt = "This is your "+name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
var txt = jQuery.validator.format("This is your {0}","Brian");
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/jQuery.validator.format